# How to keep only columns that match between dataframes?

Tags: r

Say I have two dataframes like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(state = c("ME", "TX", "CA", "NY"),
              city = c("Bangor", "Austin", "Sacramento", "New York"),
              district = c(4, 7, 19, 21))
df2 <- data.frame(state = c("MA", "WA", "NH", "FL"),
              city = c("Boston", "Seattle", "Concord", "Tampa"),
              population = c(2000000, 4000000, 80000, 2500000))
```

and I want to subset each dataframe to keep only those columns that match between the two dataframes, like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(state = c("ME", "TX", "CA", "NY"),
              city = c("Bangor", "Austin", "Sacramento", "New York"))
df2 <- data.frame(state = c("MA", "WA", "NH", "FL"),
              city = c("Boston", "Seattle", "Concord", "Tampa"))
```

How can I do this? Obviously the real data sets contain many more columns, so a generalizable approach is much preferred. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `intersect` function is your friend here:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

df1 <- data.frame(state = c("ME", "TX", "CA", "NY"),
                  city = c("Bangor", "Austin", "Sacramento", "New York"),
                  district = c(4, 7, 19, 21))

df2 <- data.frame(state = c("MA", "WA", "NH", "FL"),
                  city = c("Boston", "Seattle", "Concord", "Tampa"),
                  population = c(2000000, 4000000, 80000, 2500000))

common_names <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))


select(df1, common_names)
#>   state       city
#> 1    ME     Bangor
#> 2    TX     Austin
#> 3    CA Sacramento
#> 4    NY   New York

select(df2, common_names)
#>   state    city
#> 1    MA  Boston
#> 2    WA Seattle
#> 3    NH Concord
#> 4    FL   Tampa
```

Answer (score 1):

Use intersect to get an intersection of columns

```
col_extracted <- intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))

df1 <- df1[,col_extracted]
df2 <- df2[,col_extracted]
```